# Style an HTML table to look like a Spreadsheet like Google Docs

Tags: html, css, spreadsheet, contenteditable

I am trying to create a simple spreadsheet (with a REST/JSON back end) that looks like the Google Docs spreadsheet (or Excel).
I have a working model which uses HTML input boxes and Select boxes.
[image: Simple HTML spreadsheet]

Is there a way to style this so that it looks like a real spreadsheet and uses "ContentEditable=true" and also to handle the Tab keys?

Comment: Please show your current HTML and styling.

Answer (score 2):

You can try with this: https://mindmup.github.io/editable-table/ it works with bootstrap, allows edit content, its like a excel spreadsheet but works on a normal HTML table.

It looks like this img: [Image editableTableWidget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dakr7.png). Obviusly you can custom the style in css.